# After Form Submission, it does not clear or reset the html element.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple form layout that requires the user to input a code. Now that code will determine what php script to execute, but nonetheless this isn't my problem. You see when the user types in something wrong, the page does what it is supposed to do and give the user an error message saying.. Wrong code yadadada. But when the user goes back to type in the right code, it still gives the error.. unless the user refreshes the page and types the right code on the first try only then will it allow them to pass.

I have to have that

```
event.preventDefault();
```

because otherwise if the user types in the wrong code, it automatically refreshes the page and doesn't let the user know the code is wrong. How can i get past this? I tried setting the html field to blank, but that doesn't seem to help

```
<form id="formRSVP" method="post" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rsvpCode"><span id="rsvpTitle">RSVP Code:  </span></label>
                    <br />
                    <span id="formErrorMsg" style="color:red;"></span>
                    <input id= "rsvpCodeInput" type="code" class="form-control" name="rsvpCodeInput" placeholder="Enter RSVP Code here..">
                </div>
                <div id="rsvpFormSubmit">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $("#rsvpFormSubmit").click(function(){
                        var userInput = $('#rsvpCodeInput').val().toLowerCase();
                        $('#formRSVP').submit(function(event){
                            if(userInput === 'emoya' || userInput === 'rehersal'){
                                if(userInput === 'emoya'){
                                    $('#formRSVP').attr("action","rsvp_wedding.php");
                                }
                                else if(userInput === 'rehersal'){
                                    $('#formRSVP').attr("action","rsvp_rehersal.php");
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("This shouldn't be displaying, if it is, please email: duan_uys@icloud.com.");    
                                }
                                return;
                            }
                            else{
                                event.preventDefault();
                                $('#formErrorMsg').text('Confirmation Code Invalid. Please try again.').show();
                                alert('For testing purposes, type in either: emoya or rehersal');
                                $("#rsvpCodeInput").val('');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </form>
```

Comment: why are you using a form element at all if you're just gonna halt it?  And why are you placing a `click` handler on the wrapping `<div>` instead of just doing everything inside the `.submit()`?

Comment: because the user has to input a specific code, if not then it will display incorrect code, and reset the form. Also to allow the use of 'enter' on some browsers.

Comment: well if that's what you're comfortable with that's cool but it's not necessary.  here's what I use on my sites:  http://pastebin.com/vUAWjWL7  you can see it in action at https://cfg.io  PS - there's not anything particularly wrong with using the form but I like to make sure people are aware of the other options available.

Comment: thankyou @Deryck that is exactly what needed to be done!! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Sure thing :) I'm gonna put it as an answer in case someone else has this issue down the road and needs to find it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is most likely because `userInput` **never changes** after the first entry.

I'm betting you hit enter to submit it and that's bypassing your variable assignment. Try removing your `.click()` from the outside of your `.submit()` and put the `var userInput = $('#rsvpCodeInput').val().toLowerCase();` just inside of `.submit()`.

The `.click()` is already an understood event that occurs with `.submit()` (actually vice versa). Having it puts an extra `.submit()` fire when the button is clicked.